# How to convert data

Tags: java, android

I want to convert 2014-04-26T19:22:28.000+05:30 into dd-mm-yyyy.

I use :

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter, FORMATTER;
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.000hh:mm");
String oldDate = BeginDate.getProperty("BeginDate").toString(); //  "2011-03-10T11:54:30.207Z";`enter code here`
Date date = formatter.parse(oldDate.substring(0, 25));
FORMATTER = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");

lstTemp.add("Start Date : " +FORMATTER.format(date) );
```

I get following error :

Unpraseable date : "2014-04-26T19:22:28.000+05:30"

Comment: This title is so explicit.

Answer (score 4):

change your pattern this way

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
```

1. SSS stays for milliseconds
2. Z for the timezone

Comment: Why should it not ? The OP will answer

Answer (score 0):

```
Date parsed = new Date(Long.parseLong(dateS.substring(6,
                    dateS.length() - 2)));

            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy hh:mmaa");
            System.out.println(sdf.format(parsed));
```

Hiii, i have done recently in my apps.just pass your date in dates String and change the format which u want to like.do that its working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use joda-time:

```
    DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MM-yyyy").print(DateTime.parse("2014-04-26T19:22:28.000+05:30"))
```

Since your input is an ISO date/time, it parses correctly with `DateTime.parse()`